# how to list all instances of an application?

Tags: kill, top

How do I list all instances of an application.
ie I am running 12 instances of application called "tcpA"
I would like to list all of them.

Below is top, I don't know if there is a way to look at a certain "command"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application is called tcpA, try:

```
ps -C tcpA
```

You can restrict which processes top shows by passing it a pid, or list of pids, eg:

```
top -p 1154, 761
```

Will show just procesess 1154 and 761.

If you wanted to automate or combine those commands, using `h -o pid` with ps will limit output to just pids (eg, try `ps h -o pid -C bash`) -- getting those into a comma separated list in a string takes a little more work.

Comment: Or `pidof tcpA`.